# Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension;

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, android-studio-3.0

I'm using RxJava with Retrofit on the newest preview of AndroidStudio. My project has java 1.8 suport enabled like this:

```
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
```

But when the code is compiled and run I'm getting this error, as soon as the request is made, even if I have the `onError` handler:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension;
at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:281)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:58)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromObservable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromObservable.java:31)
at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12218)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnBackpressureLatest.subscribeActual(FlowableOnBackpressureLatest.java:31)
at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12218)
```

This happens even if I use Maybe, Single or Observable. How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is in fact not RxJava error neither Retrofit. It is Instant run error, i disabled it and my app launched.

As a temporary solution, you can disable `Instant run`, too.

To do it, go to `Build, Execution, Development` -> `Instant Run` in Settings.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works! I was in panic.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea when they are going to fix this ?

Comment: Has anyone reported this bug yet?

Comment: @ChadBingham Already here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64527520

Comment: did'nt work for me. For other workarounds check:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45614512/4875101