# Error Building Signed apk: Main Dex Capacity Exceeded

Tags: android, build, dex

I can run my app successfully in debug mode but when I try to generate a signed apk, I get the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:bolts.AggregateException: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.analytics.Session: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.targeting.TargetingClient: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.SignatureChecker: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.SafeKeyGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.bumptech.glide.signature.ApplicationVersionSignature: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.facebook.accountkit.internal.ConsoleLogger: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.facebook.common.internal.Throwables: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.facebook.common.logging.FLogDefaultLoggingDelegate: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.facebook.imageutils.WebpUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.facebook.internal.Logger: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.accountshelper.service.WorkerService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.AlbumPage: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.ArtistPage: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.GenreSelection: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.Home: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.NilandPlayer: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.PlaylistActivity: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.PlaylistTracks: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.RadioPlayer: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.SeriesActivity: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.Splash: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.TrackPlayer: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.UserInfo: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.activity.VideoPlayer: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.dialog.CreateCollectionDialog: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.dialog.PlaylistEditDialog: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.dialog.SurveyDialog: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.AlbumsFragment: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.ArtistsFragment: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.Discover: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.FMRadio: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.GenresFragment: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.PlaylistOverview$PlaylistTrackDialog: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.fragment.SongsFragment: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.service.DownloadService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.service.FetcherService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.service.LoaderService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.service.LocalMusicService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.service.MusicService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.service.StartUpService: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.utils.DownloadUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.radioafrica.music.utils.FeaturedFavoritesUtil: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:com.thin.downloadmanager.DownloadDispatcher: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils: can't find referenced class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
Warning:there were 93 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Too many classes in --main-dex-list, main dex capacity exceeded
Information:BUILD FAILED in 3m 22s
Information:1 error
Information:47 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My `Application` class extends `MultidexApplication` and I am using `v1.0.2` of the `Multidex` Library.

The following is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.1'
        classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.9.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven" }
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 75
        versionName "0.9.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexKeepProguard file("proguard.multidex.config")
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.16@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.andrognito.kerningview:kerningview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-pinpoint:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.3.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.0.2"
    compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha3'
    compile 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch:3.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch-processor:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My proguard rules are as follows:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /home/kombo/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses
-include ../proguard-com.twitter.sdk.android.twitter.txt
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.android.support.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses, LineNumberTable
-keep class com.google.code.gson.**
-keep class com.github.ksoichiro.**
-keep class org.jsoup.**
-keep class com.mcxiaoke.volley.**
-keep class de.hdodenhof.**
-keep class jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.**
-keep class com.ms-square.**
-keep class com.nineoldandroids.**
-keep class jp.wasabeef.**
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class * { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
# rxjava
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
}
-keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
}
-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    long producerNode;
    long consumerNode;
}
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
#-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
#    public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
#}
# Class names are needed in reflection
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
# Request handlers defined in request.handlers
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler
# The following are referenced but aren't required to run
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
# Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
# The SDK has several references of Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.metrics.**
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses, LineNumberTable
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
-dontwarn **$$Lambda$*
-dontwarn com.mixpanel.**
-keep class com.airbnb.deeplinkdispatch.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     @com.airbnb.deeplinkdispatch.DeepLink <methods>;
}
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
## Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
#-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
## Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
#-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding the following rule:

```
-keep class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension
```

Also, keep an eye on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604099/rxjavaplugins-error-didnt-find-class-com-google-devtools-build-android-desugar), as it may be related too (affects Gradle plugin 3.0 beta 1 and beta 3, beta 2 is not affected).

Finally, in case tha app compiled but crashed, you could use Android Studio 3.0 APK Analyzer to diagnose this. In AS 3.0 there is an option to load ProGuard mapping files to view what changes has ProGuard done to your APK.

See this [blog post](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/index.html) and [this video](https://youtu.be/rHiA66zUv8c?t=5m5s) (around minute 5).

Comment: I've tried that but it still wont generate a signed apk.

Comment: When you say "I've tried that", you mean the rule or also what is in the other SO question?

Comment: I've tried both the rule and what was in the other SO question.

Comment: I've changed the rule to try to make sure the class is kept.

Comment: I've changed the rule and it's been building for over 15 mins now. I'll just downgrade to beta 2 as Google recommends.