# Issue: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method printStackTrace(Ljava/lang/Throwable;) in Google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, apk, release, prelaunch

I am getting pre launch report in my playstore as this:

**Error Log -**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method printStackTrace(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V in class Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension' appears in /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1/base.apk)
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: com.veblr.videomate, PID: 17578
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method printStackTrace(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V in class Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.runtime.ThrowableExtension' appears in /data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.crawler-1/base.apk)
    at com.veblr.videomate.SpashScreenActiviy.updateAndroidSecurityProvider(Unknown Source)
    at com.veblr.videomate.VideoPlayerActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6013)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:148)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:466)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:420)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:234)
    at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:140)
    at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:123)
    at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:170)
    at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31)
    at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:46)
    at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:136)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:355)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:242)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:62)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:149)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:146)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is my logcat which is showing inthe report.
I can not find out what the problem is with my app.

This is the device in which the error is showing :

[image: Tested device]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there's at least someone else experiencing the same issue as yours: [App crash due to not found exception method printStateTrace](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70309653) in Android issue tracker.

Maybe if you can provide additional information they will be able to investigate the issue.

Another [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604099/rxjavaplugins-error-didnt-find-class-com-google-devtools-build-android-desugar/45614512#45614512) was because of a bug in Gradle plugin, so maybe you can try to update it.

Comment: I upgraded my gradle and it fixed the issue.